# How to write a custom where clause in JPA orm.xml file

Tags: spring-boot, jpa, orm, spring-data-jpa

My Springboot application has orm.xml file in my WEB-INF folder. 
I have few named native queries in the orm.xml file.

I want to add a where condition in the query based on the values in the parameter to the query.

I am looking for some thing like this:

```
 <named-native-query name="MyReport.countInventory">
        <query>
        SELECT COUNT(*) AS COUNT
        FROM
          Inventory
        WHERE 
         <if :date>
             add_date = :date
         </if>
        </query>
    </named-native-query>
```

Comment: The query is a STRING. No `<if>` nonsense

Comment: Such simple cases can be handled like `where (:date is null or add_date = :date)`.

Comment: @Turo This is an example. Its going to be a little complex with multiple conditions

Answer (score 1):

This is not possible with JPA.
It just allows straight-forward SQL statements without any conditional processing.

In many cases, one can actually implement the required conditional logic in SQL itself as *Turo* described in his/her comment.

Since you are seeming to be using Spring Data JPA you can also use `Specifications` to dynamically create conditions.

Another alternative would be to use [MyBatis](http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/) which allows constructing SQL statements in a way similar to what you outline in your question.
The following example is taken from http://www.mybatis.org/mybatis-3/dynamic-sql.html

```
<select id="findActiveBlogWithTitleLike"
     resultType="Blog">
  SELECT * FROM BLOG
  WHERE state = ‘ACTIVE’
  <if test="title != null">
    AND title like #{title}
  </if>
</select>
```